# taking the ord() function from a string and returning the sum

Tags: python-3.x, ord

For this code I'm trying to add up the numerical codes that correspond to the letters of the string in ASCII and then return the number, however the error is

```
ord() expected a character, but string of length 8 found
```

but I thought I had already split the string to avoid this

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
def checksum(string):
    words = string.split()
    for i in words:
        num = ord(i)[0] + ord(i)[1:]
    return num
```

For example if the string is 'hi' then the output should be 301

Comment: `ord` works on *characters* so if `i` is not a single *character* it won't work... what is `words` showing you... what would you expect an input of `hello world` to be? That'll give you two words... both each of 5 letters...

Comment: Also - shouldn't `hi` be 209 and not 301 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a one liner which might be a good pythonic way to do it

```
 def sum_string(string):
     return sum(map(ord, string))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the way you are summing the letters in the string is wrong. Try this instead:

```
string = 'hello world'

def sum_string(string):
     num = 0
     for letter in string:
         num += ord(letter)
     return num

sum_string(string)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call a function `sum` - it shadows the builtin :)

Comment: And I suppose the function can just be: `return sum(ord(ch) for ch in string)`...

Comment: Yup! However, since OP was confusing indexing with splicing syntax, I'm assuming he's fairly new to Python. So I thought a traditional loop would be more readable for him.

Comment: True... also not quite sure what ASCII system will give you 301 for "hi" either but... we may never know :)

Comment: maybe he's counting in base ~12.2? :P

Answer (score -2):

```
ord("h") # 105
ord("hi") # TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

When you are using `ord()` built-in function, only **a single character** is allowed as a parameter.

```
def check_sum(s):
    sum = 0
    for letter in s:
        sum += ord(letter)
    return sum

print(check_sum("hi")) # 209
```

By the way, `list` in this function is unnecessary. Since you could already iterate through string type itself.